# P5.js class not identified

Tags: javascript, class, identifier, unexpected-token

**i recently started using JavaScript before i used C#**. I am making a little game engine using p5.js and when i run the code i get a (SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier) error i have looked into this and found nothing that works
this is the code

- I'm sorry if this is just some messup between C# and JavaScript but like i said I'm new to JavaScript

````
  class Vector
{
    
    public int x = 0;
    
    public int y = 0;
    
    public Vector2(int xPosition,int yPosition)
    {
        x = xPosition;
        
        y = yPosition;
    }
    
}

class Color
{
    public var r;
    public var a;
    public var g;
    public var b;
    
        public Color(var red,var green,var blue,var alpha)
        {
            r = red;
            g = green;
            b = blue;
            a = alpha;
        }
    
}

class PixelBit
{
    public Vector2 position;
    
    public Color pixelColor;
    
    public PixelBit(Vector2 pixelPosition,Color color)
    {
        position = pixelPosition;
        
        pixelColor = color;
    }
    
}

static class Converters
{
    
    public static Vector2 StringToVector2(String string)
    {
        String[] splitString = string.split(",");
        
        Vector2 outputVector2 = new Vector2(int.parse(splitString[0]),int.parse(splitString[1]),int.parse(splitString[2]));
        
        return outputVector2;
        
    } 
    
    public static Color StringToColor(String sting)
    {
        String[] splitString = string.split(",");
        
        Color outputColor = new Color(int.parse(splitString[0]),int.parse(splitString[1]),int.parse(splitString[2]));
        
        return outputColor;
        
    }
    
}

class Sprite
{
    public Vector2 position;
    
    public PixelBit[] spritePixels;
    
    public function DrawSpriteOnToCanvas()
    {
        
        loadPixels();
    
        for(var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for(var p = 0; p < spritePixels.Length; p++)
                {
                    if(spritePixels[p].position.x + position.x = x && spritePixels[p].position.y + position.y = y)
                    {
                        var indx = (x + y * width) * 4;
                        
                        pixels[indx+0] = spritePixels[p].pixelColor.r;
                        pixels[indx+1] = spritePixels[p].pixelColor.a;
                        pixels[indx+2] = spritePixels[p].pixelColor.g;
                        pixels[indx+3] = spritePixels[p].pixelColor.b;
                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        updatePixels();
        
    }
    
    
    public Sprite(String spriteFile)
    {
        
        String[] splitString = spriteFile.split("|");
        
        position = Converters.StringToVector2(splitString[0]);
            
        //splits the colors up
        String[] splitColorString = splitString[1].split(".");
            
        spritePixels = new PixelBit[splitColorString.Length];
            
        for(var p = 0; p < splitColorString.Length; p++)
        {
            spritePixels[p].pixelColor = Converters.StringToColor(splitColorString[p]);
        }
        
        //splits the pixel positions up
        String[] splitVectorString = splitString[2].split(".");
            
        for(var p = 0; p < splitColorString.Length; p++)
        {
            spritePixels[p].position = Converters.StringToVector2(splitVectorString[p]);
        }
    }
}

function setup()
 {
  createCanvas(200,200);
  pixelDensity(1);
  
  
  //makes sprite1
  
  String sprite1Txt = loadStrings("Sprite1.txt");
  
  Sprite sprite1 = new Sprite(sprite1Txt);
  
}

function draw() 
{
    background(51);
    
    loadPixels();
    
    
    
    
    
    updatePixels();
    
    
    
} ```
````

Comment: This looks like you're trying to use [Processing](https://processing.org/) which is Java based. You'll need to convert that to javascript to use in p5.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I see your syntax is all wrong, you can check some tips on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_class.asp#:%7E:text=A%20class%20is%20a%20type,the%20class%20object%20is%20initialized.)  for bascis or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/search?q=class).
Also you are not declaring the P5 library anywhere, so It is never going to load. here's an example on how to declare a library [Import Library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)